# nginx cors error for prefligth request for chrome [backend tomcat server]

Tags: nginx, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy, preflight, nginx-cache

hello i am using ngnix as a static server
I am getting a error in chrome only [ Ensure preflight responses are valid ]

i tried
proxy_hide_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' true always
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network' true always
proxy_redirect off
proxy_http_version 1.1
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'
add_header Content-Type text/plain
add_header Content-Length 0

if ($request_method = OPTIONS){
return 204 "No Content"}

please help me reslove this problem and send a config which can deal this
and i am using tomcat server as my proxy pass , if i could change anything in tomcat server side also let me know